# Basic login and redirection System Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, yaml

I'm a very beginner with Symfony, and in my learning process, I have to make an authentification system with a traditional login form.

I've 3 entities : User, Recette and Ingredient. I want to use User to log in RecetteController and IngredientController only after connection and retrieve the User logged afterwards. Also to redirect to the /login url when the User is not logged

After reading a lot of tutorial including [this one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html), I can't get it work. When I logged in, I always come back on the same page, whereas I set a `default_target_path: admin_recette_new` in my security.yml I don't know why.

Here are my files:

security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    our_db_provider:
          entity:
              class: F3ILCocktailBundle:User
              property: email

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login
        security: false

    authentification:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: admin_recette_new

        logout:
                path:   logout
                target: /login


#    access_control:
#         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    main:
        #anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        pattern:   ^/admin
        provider:  our_db_provider
        anonymous: true

encoders:
    F3ILCocktailBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
```

routing.yml

```
    f3_il_cocktail:
    resource: "@F3ILCocktailBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

login.:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: F3ILCocktailBundle:Security:login}
logout:
    path:   /logout
```

SecurityController

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
       // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
        //return $this->render('F3ILCocktailBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 400px">
        <h2>Please Sign In</h2>
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}
<form class="form-signin" method='post' action='{{path('login')}}'>
    {% if error %}
        <div class='red'>{{ error.message }}</div><br>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">User Name</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputName" name='_username' class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Connection</button>
</form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

RecetteController

```
class RecetteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all recette entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="admin_recette_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $recettes = $em->getRepository('F3ILCocktailBundle:Recette')->findAll();

        return $this->render('recette/index.html.twig', array(
            'recettes' => $recettes,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new recette entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="admin_recette_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $recette = new Recette();

        $form = $this->createForm('F3ILCocktailBundle\Form\RecetteType', $recette);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($recette);
            $em->flush($recette);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_recette_show', array('id' => $recette->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('recette/new.html.twig', array(
            'recette' => $recette,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a recette entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_recette_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Recette $recette)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($recette);

        return $this->render('recette/show.html.twig', array(
            'recette' => $recette,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing recette entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_recette_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Recette $recette)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($recette);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('F3ILCocktailBundle\Form\RecetteType', $recette);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_recette_edit', array('id' => $recette->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('recette/edit.html.twig', array(
            'recette' => $recette,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a recette entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_recette_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Recette $recette)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($recette);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($recette);
            $em->flush($recette);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_recette_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a recette entity.
     *
     * @param Recette $recette The recette entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Recette $recette)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('admin_recette_delete', array('id' => $recette->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Please where I'm wrong ? Thx for your help

Comment: The login system expects params to be named ` _username ` and ` _password `

Comment: I just changed ` email ` into ` _username `  and got the exact same problem :(